# Using Math.random To Display Random Numbers and Verify The Value Is Not Already Appended To The JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, math, jtextarea

I'm working on a program to display 7 random numbers between 1 and 42 using the Math.random method while also checking that no 2 numbers generated are the same. The way I have gotten it to work so far is by creating 7 different variables and checking each one to make sure it's not equal to the previous one which is extremely inefficient! Look below:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class LottoDrawEdited {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int no1 = 0, no2 = 0, no3 = 0, no4 = 0, no5 = 0, no6 = 0, no7 = 0;
        String Numbers = "";

            no1 = (int)(Math.random()*42 + 1);
            Numbers += no1 + " ";

            no2 = (int)(Math.random()*42 + 1);
            do{
                if(no2 == no1){
                    no2 = (int)(Math.random()*42 + 1);
                }
            }while(no2 == no1);
            Numbers += no2 + " ";

            no3 = (int)(Math.random()*42 + 1);
            do{
                if(no3 == no1 || no3 == no2){
                    no3 = (int)(Math.random()*42 + 1);
                }
            }while(no3 == no1 || no3 == no2);
            Numbers += no3 + " ";

            no4 = (int)(Math.random()*42 + 1);
            do{
                if(no4 == no1 || no4 == no2 || no4 == no3){
                    no4 = (int)(Math.random()*42 + 1);
                }
            }while(no4 == no1 || no4 == no2 || no4 == no3);
            Numbers += no4 + " ";

            no5 = (int)(Math.random()*42 + 1);
            do{
                if(no5 == no1 || no5 == no2 || no5 == no3 || no5 == no4){
                    no5 = (int)(Math.random()*42 + 1);
                }
            }while(no5 == no1 || no5 == no2 || no5 == no3 || no5 == no4);
            Numbers += no5 + " ";

            no6 = (int)(Math.random()*42 + 1);
            do{
                if(no6 == no1 || no6 == no2 || no6 == no3 || no6 == no4 || no6 == no5){
                    no6 = (int)(Math.random()*42 + 1);
                }
            }while(no6 == no1 || no6 == no2 || no6 == no3 || no6 == no4 || no6 == no5);
            Numbers += no6 + " ";

            no7 = (int)(Math.random()*42 + 1);
            do{
                if(no7 == no1 || no7 == no2 || no7 == no3 || no7 == no4 || no7 == no5 || no7 == no6){
                    no7 = (int)(Math.random()*42 + 1);
                }
            }while(no7 == no1 || no7 == no2 || no7 == no3 || no7 == no4 || no7 == no5 || no7 == no6);
            Numbers += no7 + " ";

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The Lotto Numbers Are:\n" + Numbers,"Lotto Draw",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

As you can see it looks awful. Before I started this way I was trying to figure out whether I could:

- Only Have 1 Variable
- Generate the first variable
- Append the first variable to a JTextArea
- Clear the first variable
- Generate the second variable
- Somehow check if that matches the 1st variable which is already appended onto the JTextArea?

That way would be much more efficient and would take significantly less code but I can't manage to work my head around it with any other more efficient solution. What would be the best way to go about doing it more efficiently and does my logic above make any sense when it comes to using JTextArea?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You could put each value you calculate into a `List` or `Set` and check it to see if you've already used and calculate a new one if you have

Answer (score 1):

You could put each value you calculate into a `List` or `Set` and check it to see if you've already used and calculate a new one if you have.

Something along the lines of...

```
 List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(25);
 //...
 int value = -1;
 do {
     value = (int)(Math.random()*42 + 1);
 } while (values.contains(value));
 values.add(value);
 textArea.append(Integer.toString(value) + "\n");
```

... for example...

You could wrap the generation of the numbers into a method to make it eaiser...

```
public int getNextNumber() {
    int value = -1;
    do {
        value = (int)(Math.random()*42 + 1);
    } while (values.contains(value));
    values.add(value);
    return value;
}
```

This would assume you've made the `values` `List` and instance field...

Take a look at [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details

**Updated**

If using a `List` is to complex or not allowed, you could roll your own functionality using arrays, for example...

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    private int[] values = new int[6];
    private int count = 0;

    public Test() {
        for (int index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
            System.out.println(getNextNumber());
        }
    }

    public int getNextNumber() {

        int value = -1;

        if (count < values.length) {

            do {
                value = (int) (Math.random() * 42 + 1);
            } while (contains(value));
            values[count] = value;
            count++;

        }

        return value;

    }

    protected boolean contains(int value) {
        Arrays.sort(values);
        return Arrays.binarySearch(values, value) >= 0;
    }

}
```

This becomes a little more complex, as you need to guard against `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`s

Now, if `Arrays.sort` and `Arrays.binarySearch` are to complex or not allowed, you could change it for something like...

```
private boolean contains(int value) {
    boolean contains = false;
    for (int check : values) {
        if (value == check) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return contains;
}
```

Which will do the same job...

Comment: If you're not familiar with what a `List` or `Set` ADT is you can simply just use an array and write your own contains() method. I like this approach even though you're basically re-inventing the wheel, it gives you a better understanding of how the language works overall.

Comment: @MrZalib True, I'm just lazy ;)

Comment: I was just about to comment saying that my knowledge with java is pretty limited!! I know all basics, like the Scanner method, I've just started teaching myself GUI based java with the past 2/3 weeks so I'm pretty unfamiliar you could say with 'Lists' and 'Sets' although I am reading a bit on them now looking at the "Collections Trail" link to try and grasp the solution mentioned!

Comment: @alannm37 The above example uses a `ArrayList` which is basically a dynamic array (it can grow and shrink automatically, allowing you to add new values to it and remove old ones from it).  So if you understand arrays, then `ArrayList` should be familiar...it just has some additional functionality wrapped around it

Comment: @lannm37 If you're starting out learning the language I wouldn't suggest learning an ADT like MadProgrammer suggests. I'm going to take a guess that this is a project for a class. What programming classes that I've taken follow the philosophy of, "If you haven't learned about it yet, it better not be in your program." Just keep that in mind if you choose to use a `ArrayList`. Your prof might not like it.

Comment: @MrZalib I've started learning Java last summer so I am pretty new like but I won't back down from challenging myself to work things out :) Your guess is somewhat understandable but not true, I'm actually learning HTML and C in college. I just work on Java myself in my own time from different websites as I want to broaden my horizons as they say. So I am going to try wrap my head around this suggested solution for now. In the meantime, don't hesitate to add other possibilities if ye would like because really, anything will help me learn! Thanks guys.

Comment: @alannm37: In that case I'd say go for it. I see MadProgrammer updated his answer to include a solution that includes using an array instead. This is pretty much what I'd put down to so that saves me some time ;)